# How to navigate to to different directories in the terminal (mac)?

Tags: macos, terminal

I have just installed sass and I am now tryring to access the sass file. For example:

```
sass --watch ~/Desktop/sass/css/style.css:style.css
```

and the error is "no such file or directory" - So how can I do this?

My mac version is 10.6.8

Answer (score 47, accepted):

To check that the file you're trying to open actually exists, you can change directories in terminal using `cd`. To change to `~/Desktop/sass/css`: `cd ~/Desktop/sass/css`. To see what files are in the directory: `ls`.

If you want information about either of those commands, use the `man` page: `man cd` or `man ls`, for example.

Google for "basic unix command line commands" or similar; that will give you numerous examples of moving around, viewing files, etc in the command line.

On Mac OS X, you can also use `open` to open a finder window: `open .` will open the current directory in finder. (`open ~/Desktop/sass/css` will open the `~/Desktop/sass/css`).