# Running a Github iOS project containing Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, github, cocoapods

I'm quite new to iOS development. Let's say I want to use a UI element from Github that uses Cocoapods.

Like this one:

[Whisper by hyperslo](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Whisper)

After downloading the zip file from Github:

[image]

Could someone give a step-by-step guide to

1. Run the demo project
2. Integrate the UI element into my own project

Thanks!

Comment: Have you installed Cocoapods and read their documentation? Have you read the installation instructions right there on the main page of the Github project you wish to use? Have you opened the Xcode project for the Github project and built and run the demo app?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes I have installed Cocoapods, but its documentation has quite a steep learning curve. The installation instruction mentioned "adding 'pod 'Whisper'' to your Podfile", which I don't really understand. Which file is the Podfile? Thanks for your time!

Comment: This is why you need to read the Cocoapods documentation. It covers all of this step-by-step. Your question is basically asking us to repost the Cocoapods documentation.

Comment: Go to https://guides.cocoapods.org and read "Getting Started" and "Using CocoaPods". Then read the instructions from the Github project. That should be enough.

Comment: @maddy Actually, I can kind of relate to the OP. When I learned how to use cocoa pods I felt it had a steep learning curve...

Comment: @rmaddy I believe the Cocoapods documentation presumes a lot of prior knowledge. "Create a Podfile, and add your dependencies" might  only make sense to someone experienced. Thanks anyways!

Comment: It makes no assumptions. Right under that is shows you a sample Podfile. And the Podfile link shows you all the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the demo *is* a little tricky. Apparently you have to first do a `pod install`, then open the workspace.

Make sure you have cocoa pods installed. For how to install it, go to https://cocoapods.org

Use the command line to navigate to the directory where the `.xcworkspace` file is located i.e. `/Whisper-master/Demo/WhisperDemo`

Run `pod install`

After that, open up `WhisperDemo.xcworkspace` in Xcode and you can run the demo.

To install this as a pod of your own project, you first navigate to your project's directory and do a `pod init`. A Podfile will be generated. Write in the Podfile the following:

```
platform :ios, '10.0' # or whatever your target platform is

target 'Your target's name' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Whisper'
end
```

Then do a `pod install`. From now on, *do not* open the `.xcodeproj` file. Instead, open the `.xcworkspace` whenever you want to work on the project.

Comment: Thank you for answering my "stupid" question, as I was feeling sorta uneasy seeing my question being down-voted.

Comment: @FriedPotato I think your question is not stupid at all. I encountered similar problems too when I was learning to use cocoa pods.

Comment: For those wondering how to navigate directories using the command line (Terminal), see [How to navigate to to different directories in the terminal (mac)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547730/how-to-navigate-to-to-different-directories-in-the-terminal-mac)

Comment: @FriedPotato No one thinks your question is stupid. The down votes are most likely because your question doesn't appear to show any research effort and it is basically asking people to summarize what is already documented. If your question showed some effort and some attempt then it would have been received much differently. Something to think about for future questions. Enjoy.

Comment: @rmaddy The Cocoapods documentation does contain everything I need, but those relevant to a beginner are unfortunately mixed with advanced topics. I believe summarizations done by experienced programmers are useful, and my question provides an opportunity for answers that can encourage many future beginners. Nevertheless I will keep your suggestion in mind when asking questions in the future. :)